Write code to change user email address unable to resolve class UserAccessor
I am trying to write code to change a user email address in Jira and I am getting the following error for my last import
unable to resolve class
 com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor

Anyone knows how this can be fixed? I am using Jira Service Management 5.12.11 and Jira Software 9.12.11. Anyone knows how to fix the problem?
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserManager;
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.parameters.annotation.ShortTextInput
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.DefaultUserService
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor
@ShortTextInput(label = 'File path', description = '\\itrac-tst\\mouh-share\\newMailAddress.txt')
String csvFilePath
def userAccessor = ComponentLocator.getComponent(UserAccessor)
// Edit the file path below to your user csv file path
def file = new File(csvFilePath)
def csvMapList = []
file.eachLine {
        // Read each line of a CSV file to form a user map
        line ->
                def columns = line.split(",")
                def tmpMap = [:]
                tmpMap.putAt("username", columns[0])
                tmpMap.putAt("original_email", columns[2])
                csvMapList.add(tmpMap)
}
log.debug(csvMapList)
def accountsUpdated = 0
csvMapList.each {
        // Iterate through each user in map and update user emails
        map ->
                def userName = map["username"] as String
                def originalEmail = map["original_email"] as String
                // Edit new_email to the new domain you want to use
                def newEmail = originalEmail.split('@')[0].concat("@new_email.com")
                if (userAccessor.exists(userName)) {
                        def originalUser = userAccessor.getUserByName(userName)
                        def modifiedUser =  UserManager.getUser(originalUser)
                        modifiedUser.setEmail(newEmail)
                        userAccessor.saveUser(modifiedUser)
                        if (userAccessor.getUserByName(userName).getEmail() == newEmail) {
                                log.debug("Successfully updated " + userName + "'s email from " + originalEmail + " to " + newEmail)
                                accountsUpdated++
                        } else {
                                log.debug(userName + "'s email was not successfully updated.")
                        }
                } else {
                        log.debug("User " + userName + " was not found.")
                }
}
log.debug("User update completed. Successfully updated " + accountsUpdated + " accounts.")

I have tried to write it in the script console but the import is the problem


Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code
block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run
the code to reproduce your issue.
